# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

Full exception message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:
> Schedular.API.Models.TaskSchedule schedule, Schedular.API.Models.Note
> note>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Schedular.API.Models.TaskSchedule>'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> [Schedular.API]

```cs
public async Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetTaskSchedulesByUser(int UserId)
{           
    var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
        .Join(_context.Notes, 
              schedule => schedule.Id, 
              note => note.Id, 
              (schedule, note) => new { schedule, note })
        .Where(u => u.schedule.userId == UserId)
        .ToListAsync(); 

    return userTaskSchedule;            
}
```

I believe the return type of the method needs changing but I am not sure to what.

Models

parent table = taskSchedule

child table = notes

Notes model

```
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NotesInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated {get; set;}
    public TaskSchedule taskSchedule {get; set;}
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; } 
}
```

TaskSchedule Model

```
public class TaskSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: What flavour of ORM is this? I'm not sure you need the join.. Looks like you might just want `return await _context.TaskSchedules.Where(u => u.schedule.userId == UserId).ToListAsync()` judging by the method signature. If you want to return notes too, and there is no place for a note to be kept in a TaskSchedule, you'll need to modify the method return type

Comment: ORM = Entityframework
I need notes as its on a separate table. "Taskschedule" has a 1 to many relationship with "Note". I should be able to add as many notes to the "taskschedule". The code you have written was originally the code I had, which worked, however, I could not view notes. Is there anyway to join it to the notes table?

Comment: Could i request you tag your question with it the version (and whether it's core/not) eg tag with with `efcore` and `efcore-3.1`. Does TaskSchedule have a nav property to notes? EF questions are usually a lot easier to answer when you include the entitiy classes and their mapping configs

Comment: I've added the models

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The JOIN created a new anonymous type that doesn't match combining both a TaskSchedule and a Note that *doesn't* match the return type. If you didn't want to return both types, why join with Notes?

Comment: Besides, JOINs are generated by the ORM based on the relations between entities. If you have to explicitly use a JOIN, it's a VERY strong indication that the model and entities are wrong. TaskSchedule should have a Note or Notes property

Comment: Even if he wanted to join for whatever reason, the projection is wrong. It would be `(schedule, note) => schedule`

Comment: Is there a way to return both types or am I not meant to use join when using ORM?
How do I add notes to taskschedule. The relationship is for one taskSchedule, there can be many notes attached to it. How would I go about doing that in the model?

Comment: You don't return both types.. if taskschedule has a relationship with notes, then you ask EF to get you the taskschedules, includes the notes, and just return the lsit of TS, - the notes go with them because theyre related. *Got any mappings you can post too?*

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do but I keep going down the wrong path. I tried using the .include() however it will not work as I have added the relationship in the note model as I am trying to allow the one to many from the taskschedular. I can make it work if I add the notes in the taskschedular model however I will end up with a one to many from the notes, therefore, the wrong way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect your TaskSchedule to look like:

```
public class TaskSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }  

    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }  
}
```

(The Note class would still have a single TaskSchedule property - EF can infer that TS:N is 1:M as a result because one end of the rel is a single property and the other end is a collection)

And to get task schedules and their notes you could e.g. say:

```
public async Task<IList<TaskSchedule>> GetTaskSchedulesByUser(int UserId)
{           
    var userTaskSchedule = await _context.TaskSchedules
        .Include(ts => ts.Notes)
        .Where(u => u.schedule.userId == UserId)
        .ToListAsync(); 

    return userTaskSchedule;            
}
```

Bucketloads of info on [how to configure relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) and also [how to query related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)